# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method when trying to import two libraries with a common libray and an execlude rule in gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-library, kotlin-multiplatform

I have built 2 libraries with one shared module and published them on JitPack, then I tried to import both libraries in the same App and tried to run it, I got this compile time error `Duplicate class {Class name in the shared module}`, so I excluded this module in gradle

```
implementation("FIRST_LIBRARY:VERSION") {
  // exclude("FIRST_LIBRARYK", "SHARED_MODULE")
}
implementation("SECOND_LIBRARY:VERSION")
```

Now the problem is, when I try to run the App, I get this runtime error
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method ...` in the first library, and the App crashes, and If I excluded the shared library from the second one, the crash will be in the second one instead of the first.

What should be done so I can avoid the two errors ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The class not found error actually makes sense in my case as I was updating the first library which includes updates in the shared one, but never updating the second library which introduced outdated files with different versions.